# Why am i getting this error when trying to get the username of whoever is signed in so that I can display it in my shared LayoutView

Tags: c#, session, model-view-controller

> System.ArgumentException: 'The (&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=)(distinguishedName=)(name=))) search filter is invalid.'
>
> I keep getting this error when it hits this line

```
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

> Here is my full code in my base class

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected database _db { get; set; }
    protected string _userId { get; set; }
    protected string _userFullName { get; set; }

    public BaseController()
    {
        _db = new database ();

        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

        _userFullName = principal.GivenName + " " + principal.Surname;
        _userId = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).Remove(0, 4);

        ViewData["userFullName"] = _userFullName;

    }
}
```

> I am trying to grab the username from the base class and use it in my LayoutView to show the name of whoever is logged in.

Comment: I am sorry but did you use [Authorize]?

Comment: Hey I think i got it working with
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

            _userFullName = principal.GivenName + " " + principal.Surname;

Comment: this is a same code

Comment: @AlirezaMadad I know..  I spent a good 3 hours on going back and forth with this then i decided to rebuild my project and run it a couple more times and my name starting showing where I wanted it to. I HAVE NO IDEA!!

Comment: Interesting thanks for reply good luck